# Creating excel reports places all data of 1 row in same column

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel

I am creating a php excel report. This is my code.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" . $title);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
$final_Array = array();

echo "ID, Name, Description, Change Type, Datetime" . "\r\n";

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}

//Rearrage Elements and exclude unwanted data
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $final_Array[$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
    $final_Array[$key]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $final_Array[$key]['description'] = $value['description'];
    $final_Array[$key]['change_type'] = $value['change_type'];
    $final_Array[$key]['dnt'] = $value['dnt'];
}

outputCSV($final_Array);
?>
```

The issue is that all the data is placed in the first column of each row. What should I do?

Comment: It's probable that the version of MS Excel you're checking with has a locale-specific separator that isn't a comma (`'`); try using a semi-colon (`;`) as the separator instead.... this is one reason why creating csv files for MS Excel is  bad idea

Comment: In my experience, using "id" as a column name in a CSV file messes up with Excel as it tries to interpret the data. Try calling that column "identifier" or "UID"

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: @zoubida13, same error.

Comment: @MarkBaker, when I replaced commas with ; it says can not read record 32. Continue reporting... ?

Comment: Let me use my crystal ball to see what record 32 might be; or better yet, take a look at it yourself in a text editor rather than in MS Excel, so you can see what is actually being written by your script, and dnot MS Excel's interpretation of it

Comment: @MarkBaker first row is ; separated and rest are , separated

Comment: Then fix it.... it's your code that's caling `fputcsv()`, so your code needs to tell the function to use a `;` rather than a `,`.... here's the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), and it's the third argument to the function